# Woocommerce add to cart button

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, cart

If i open http://waam.minimal.com.hr/product-category/renaissance-milano/ i can see all products in that category **but i dont have add to cart button (below every product)**.  <- i want that

Add to cart button **is only displayed when i enter product**
(example - http://waam.minimal.com.hr/product/matte-grain-black-w-contemporary-lines/)

This is definetly caused by theme overwriting default woocommerce settings, but only related thing to (add_to_cart) i can find is this (functions.php).

Is that something i should change (and to what) ?

```
* Add to cart with AJAX */
    if ( $basix_options['woo_ajax_add_cart'] == TRUE ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

Comment: All your products have an add to cart button (but I am not logged in)…